# REACT: Rendering a "please fill out this field" warning On Hover

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

[image: so here is a shot of what I am trying to build: the "fill out field" part]

Hey all. 
I am trying to make this "alert" when the email input has not been filled out. I know I will need on onHover handler that specifically renders that box when it's value == "". However, I am not sure exactly how to make it, if I should for instance just render a div in that position if the input has not been filled out or if there is a better way?

Any advice appreciated! 
=)

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/14608892/7586354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a variable in the state
lets say

```
state={
    showTooltip:false
}
```

And in the onHover handler you can check the ==="" value and update the state which will re-render your component and based on state value you can render the Tooltip warning

Comment: Could you give more detail of how the tool tip will look like? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, not sure this answers the question

```
class Test extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            showAlert: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleHover(e) {
        this.setState({
            showAlert: !e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input 
                    name='email' 
                    value={this.state.email} 
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    onMouseEnter={this.handleHover}  
                />

                {this.state.showAlert 
                    ? <span>Please fill this field</span> 
                    : null }

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const InputWithToolTip = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <>
      <input 
        value={text}
        onChange={({target: {value}) => setText(value)}
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}                   
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      />
      {
        isHovered &&
        <span>I'm a tool tip!</span>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```